# Apache .htaccess redirect to nested folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect `www.example.com/folder/ -> www.example.com/folder/subfolder/`. I tried the following entries in my `.htaccess`.

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # 1
    # RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*)$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
    
    # 2
    # RewriteRule ^/folder/ https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/ [R=301,L]

    # 3
    Redirect 301 /folder/ https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder
</IfModule>
```

All of the three attempts do not work. Attempt `1` and `2` do not trigger a redirect and attempt `3` results in `too many redirects` because the pattern `/folder/` is inside `https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder`. This results in `https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder...`.
Are there any solutions available?

Comment: Check this link, Related to your questions:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1099393/htaccess-redirect-sub-folders-to-the-correspondent-index-php

Answer (score -1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/subfolder
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.*)$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

You need to consider that the matching pattern in a `RewriteRule` that is implemented in a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess") is applied to a *relative* path. You were trying to match an *absolute* path in your attempt. Which is why the rules never got applied.

That behavior is clearly documented. I recommend that you start looking into the documentation of the tool you are using. As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

The modified pattern above considers the leading slash optional (`^/?`). That way the same rule can get implemented in the http server's *central* host configuration or inside a *distributed* configuration file.

Comment: But that pattern still matches on `/folder/subfolder/`, so this would still cause a redirect loop. If the rewrite is only needed for one "level" below `folder`, then replacing `.*` with a character class that allows for everything but a slash, should work. If it needs to work for any level of folder depth, then this will probably need an additional RewriteCond to check that the currently requested path does not start with `/folder/subfolder/` already.

Comment: @arkascha Obviously its not that clearly documented if you present a not working solution. I recommend that you start looking into the documentation of the tool you are using.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for that advide. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Sorry, indeed one has to add a condition to prevent the redirection loop. I added it to the code suggestion above. I focused on the explanation why the sttempted `RewriteRule`s don't work. I missed the bit about the rewriting loop, clearly my mistake. That has _nothing_ to do with the documentation though as I am certain we all agree.

Comment: Your example still ends up in a redirection loop smh.

Comment: Yep, missed a "/" in the condition. Fixed.

Comment: Does still not work. Is it a problem that I use a deeper nested folder structure?
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder
RewriteRule ^/?folder/subfolder/(.*)$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: And "does not work" means what _exactly_ ? I do not really understand that rule you posted in the comment. Pattern and target use the same folder, that does not really make sense, does it? Or maybe I just completely miss understood what you were trying to say.